# if ul has any children then remove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have unordered list which is dynamically filled with list items. Initially this UL is empty. After some page manipulation I want to check if ul with certain id (myList) has any child element. If has any childs than remove. How this can be done using jquery?

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <ul id="myList" data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
       <li>Item 1<Li>
       <li>Item 2<Li>
       <li>Item 3<Li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Babak Naffas - why did you edit this question, giving it the exact opposite meaning what the requester wanted? The original headline was "if ul has any children than remove" and you changed it to "Remove a <ul> if it has no children"!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($("#myDiv li").length) {
    $("#myDiv").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/77/)

I think you wanted to remove li if li exists. then try like his:

```
  if($("#myDiv li").length) {
        $("#myDiv li").remove();
    }
```